# Where would be the appropriate place to ask a legal question about email/spam laws?

Tags: discussion, questions, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, legal

I have a question pertaining to the legal requirements of an "Unsubscribe" link in automated emails, for an automated email system I'm building. I'm pretty sure this is not fit for SO, and also iffy asking on Programmers.SE. Is there a more appropriate Stack Exchange site where I can ask this?

The question is more or less if I should worry about providing an unsubscribe link or not if the email is transactional.

Comment: There is no place for such question on the network at this time.

Comment: Okay, how does that make this a bad question? because I need something that isn't there?

Comment: You mean because someone downvoted you? Downvotes on this site don't necessarily mean you asked a bad question, just that the voter doesn't agree with you. Or your premise. Or whichever side of some argument he assumes you support. Or your general attitude. Here, it probably just means "there's no such site yet."

Comment: What makes you think that I'm the source of the downvote? As it happened, I was not.

Comment: @Rosinante I didn't think that, it just seemed to be the natural reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no site in the Stack Exchange network for legal questions, but there are a few proposals on Area 51.

- [Legal Questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44823/legal-questions)
- [Legal Technology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44896/legal-technology)
- [Legal Academia, Practice, and Other Law-Related Questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52687/legal-academia-practice-and-other-law-related-questions)
- [Legal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48901/legal)
- [Hacking Morality and Legality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44607/hacking-morality-and-legality)