# Best place (if any) to ask legal/law questions about software

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-recommendation, legal

Following [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54570/21486), I would like to ask, what is the best place in SE network (if any) to ask questions concerning legal part or side of software or services:

1. What user can, can't, should or shouldn't do in Facebook, Twitter and many more web apps.
2. Can I use this or that software or service commercially or legally in my company?
3. Other questions about license of particular software or service (not general law-related questions).

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173089/189165) was given a year ago. Do we have any update? Is there any *real* chance, any of mentioned Area51 sites will grow to fully-functional SE site? Or do we have any chance for any other place in SE to ask software/service-legal- related questions, not being concerned as off-topic?

Comment: You're better off raising attention (comment, bounty) on the original question which you linked to, than creating a new (dupe) question.

Comment: @James Spend my (very) little reputation to start a bounty to a question, that is already marked as off-topic? That doesn't sound like a reasonable idea, don't you think? Plus: I won't dupe this question, because -- as you can see (flags, answer) -- there isn't good place in SE network to ask questions like that.

Comment: @all I think many would disagree, that question about rules & regulations **isn't** the same as asking about licensing. So, I disagree, that this is a duplicate. We can discuss rules of using SE in SE network and I don't think we can ask about licensing SE? But... OK! If five people (at least) found this question a duplicate, then it will be closed. Pity, but true...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was once a software law Area 51 proposal, however it never launched and there's now no trace of it. You could possibly start a new proposal for it, but based on the last attempt (and the failure of the proposals in the previous answer you've linked to) it would be unlikely to get off the ground. I guess there's either not enough people out there with legal experience willing to participate, or they just don't want to provide expertise for free.

There has been the occasional licencing based question on StackOverflow. If you want your question to survive there it should be very specific and very answerable. Due to the changing nature of T&C's and licencing conditions and their wooly and sometimes vague language, it's unlikely that any answers to your questions will be valid long term (which means people are likely to close vote pretty quickly).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70444/172661

Comment: Thank you for providing great answer to a question already marked as duplicate! I have some doubts about arguments risen by you and others. My question (what is allowed on Twitter / any other service) touches grounds (fundamentals) of that service and isn't likely to be changed soon / ever. But I agree, that this is just a small example of question, that maybe could fit, while in the same time, there are many, that wouldn't fit. For this and for arguments given by you, in this answer, I now see, that chances for software-law SE site are quite low. Thanks!

Comment: Can't they be asked at http://law.stackexchange.com/ ?